# Showing a multivariable function is differentiable at a point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

So I've been asked a question:
"Show the function $f(x,y) = x^2 - xy + 3y^2$ is differentiable at the point $(1,1)$ using the definition of differentiability." The question also mentions that it wants us to indicate the linear and little-o terms, and prove the little-o terms are in fact little-o terms.

I've been given the answer already (see below) and understand most of what is going on but I'm not sure how we go from line 3 to line 4 (line 4 being the one that starts with $f(1,1)$).

I understand what happens after line 4, it's just the jump from line 3 to line 4 that I don't understand, where to these terms ($o(h)$, $A h$, and $f(1,1)$) come from?

Thanks in advance
[image: My given answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From line 3 to line 4:

$f(1,1)=3$

$h=(h_1,h_2)$ and $Ah=h_1+5h_2$

$h_1^2-h_1h_2+h_2^2=o(h)$

Comment: ok, i get the f(1,1) part, he just subbed x=1 and y=1 into the original equation. For A, did he find the value of A just by seeing the values of the constants on h1 and h2 were 1 and 5? How did o(h) appear, is that just a general formula for little-o?

Comment: @Maximus: $h_1+5h_2$ is the dot product of two vectors, $(1,5)$ and $(h_1,h_2)$.

Comment: @Maximus $h_1^2-h_1h_2+h_2^2=o(h)$ by definition of little o. Note particularly that $h=(h_1,h_2)$.

Comment: Ohhhh, ok thanks a lot, was actually pretty simple I just didn't look at it the right way.

Comment: @Maximus You are welcome. :-)